# How to make a QR code scanner in React native using expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

When I run https://snack.expo.io/@sushil62/qr-code-scanner in the expo which works fine, but when copy the same code given in App.js file, after running the application the camera opens but it shows no result while scanning, and
in expo also when changing the snack version 33 or higher it does not work there too.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Alert, Linking, Dimensions, LayoutAnimation, Text, View, StatusBar, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { BarCodeScanner, Permissions } from 'expo';

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    hasCameraPermission: null,
    lastScannedUrl: null,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this._requestCameraPermission();
  }

  _requestCameraPermission = async () => {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
    this.setState({
      hasCameraPermission: status === 'granted',
    });
  };

  _handleBarCodeRead = result => {
    if (result.data !== this.state.lastScannedUrl) {
      LayoutAnimation.spring();
      this.setState({ lastScannedUrl: result.data });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        {this.state.hasCameraPermission === null
          ? <Text>Requesting for camera permission</Text>
          : this.state.hasCameraPermission === false
              ? <Text style={{ color: '#fff' }}>
                  Camera permission is not granted
                </Text>
              : <BarCodeScanner
                  onBarCodeRead={this._handleBarCodeRead}
                  style={{
                    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
                    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
                  }}
                />}

        {this._maybeRenderUrl()}

        <StatusBar hidden />
      </View>
    );
  }

  _handlePressUrl = () => {
    Alert.alert(
      'Open this URL?',
      this.state.lastScannedUrl,
      [
        {
          text: 'Yes',
          onPress: () => Linking.openURL(this.state.lastScannedUrl),
        },
        { text: 'No', onPress: () => {} },
      ],
      { cancellable: false }
    );
  };

  _handlePressCancel = () => {
    this.setState({ lastScannedUrl: null });
  };

  _maybeRenderUrl = () => {
    if (!this.state.lastScannedUrl) {
      return;
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.bottomBar}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.url} onPress={this._handlePressUrl}>
          <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.urlText}>
            {this.state.lastScannedUrl}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.cancelButton}
          onPress={this._handlePressCancel}>
          <Text style={styles.cancelButtonText}>
            Cancel
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  };
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#000',
  },
  bottomBar: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
    padding: 15,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  url: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  urlText: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  cancelButton: {
    marginLeft: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  cancelButtonText: {
    color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.8)',
    fontSize: 18,
  },
});
```

It would be very nice if someone suggests me to solve this or give me an example(such as downgrading the expo version) so that I can implement this.

Answer (score 5):

You can use

`expo-barcode-scanner`

Run `expo install expo-barcode-scanner`

**Usage**

You must request permission to access the user's camera before attempting to get it. To do this, you will want to use the Permissions API. You can see this in practice in the following example.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Button
} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';

import {
  BarCodeScanner
} from 'expo-barcode-scanner';

export default class BarcodeScannerExample extends React.Component {
  state = {
    hasCameraPermission: null,
    scanned: false,
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.getPermissionsAsync();
  }

  getPermissionsAsync = async() => {
    const {
      status
    } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
    this.setState({
      hasCameraPermission: status === 'granted'
    });
  };

  render() {
    const {
      hasCameraPermission,
      scanned
    } = this.state;

    if (hasCameraPermission === null) {
      return <Text > Requesting
      for camera permission < /Text>;
    }
    if (hasCameraPermission === false) {
      return <Text > No access to camera < /Text>;
    }
    return ( <
      View style = {
        {
          flex: 1,
          flexDirection: 'column',
          justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        }
      } >
      <
      BarCodeScanner onBarCodeScanned = {
        scanned ? undefined : this.handleBarCodeScanned
      }
      style = {
        StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject
      }
      />

      {
        scanned && ( <
          Button title = {
            'Tap to Scan Again'
          }
          onPress = {
            () => this.setState({
              scanned: false
            })
          }
          />
        )
      } <
      /View>
    );
  }

  handleBarCodeScanned = ({
    type,
    data
  }) => {
    this.setState({
      scanned: true
    });
    alert(`Bar code with type ${type} and data ${data} has been scanned!`);
  };
}
```

**Note:** Passing undefined to the onBarCodeScanned prop will result in no scanning. This can be used to effectively "pause" the scanner so that it doesn't continually scan even after data has been retrieved.

Allow all the permisions which gets popped.

You're good to go!!

Hope this helps.

Comment: you have an error with spacing!
- but your code works after editing :)

Comment: Does this work for QR code as weel? it says barcode right in the name.

Comment: @Paschal : I am also trying it for QR. If you check expo doc it says "qr"  as Supported Formats.

Comment: @Paschal yes, the library does support QR codes.